# Two-way binding in angular 2 when updating model

Tags: angularjs, http, typescript, angular, put

I need to update my model in Angular 2.

My update method looks:

```
  putDep(item) {
   var headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.selected.departmentName = item.departmentName;
    this.selected.departmentLocation = item.departmentLocation;

  return this.http.put('http://localhost:65402/company/api/department'+ "/update/" + this.selected.departmentNo,  JSON.stringify(item),{headers: headers})
                  .subscribe(res => {this.departments = res.json();});
```

}

and HTML code:

```
 <form  #selected="ngForm" [hidden]="!showEditView" align="center">
    <div>
        <label for="editAbrv">Department No:</label><br>
        <input ngControl="departmentNo" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="editAbrv">Department name:</label><br>
        <input ngControl="departmentName" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="editAbrv">Department Location:</label><br>
        <input ngControl="departmentLocation" placeholder="location">
    </div>

    <div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="putDep(selected.value)" title="Add">
            Save
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)=showHide($event) >
            Cancel
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is in 2 way binding with model. This is how it looks in backend:

```
  [HttpPut]
            [Route("Update/{id}")]
            public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Update(int id, DepartmentModel model)
```

The problem is in that when I click to edit model, my int id pass to backend, but my model id (which should ne the same as passed id) is null. Also, when I click on edit button I cant see how change on view when I input value for model. In angular 1 I solve it fast, but in Angular 2 is struggle. The point is that I want id is automatically connected with my model when I click edit and that I can see it inside input field (as well as other 2 properties). Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `ngModel` to fix that. When selecting an element you could set a property `selectedDepartment` in your component with the department to update. You can bind then properties of this object on the inputs (only properties you want to update).

This `selectedDepartment` object contains all properties included the current identifier.

When clicking on the "Save" button, you could send this object instead of the form value. This way you wouldn't lose the identifier.

Here is the code of the form:

```
<form  #selected="ngForm" [hidden]="!showEditView" align="center">
  <div>
    <label for="editAbrv">Department No:</label><br>
    <input [(ngForm)]="selectedDepartment.departmentNo" ngControl="departmentNo" placeholder="name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="editAbrv">Department name:</label><br>
    <input [(ngForm)]="selectedDepartment.departmentName" ngControl="departmentName" placeholder="name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="editAbrv">Department Location:</label><br>
    <input [(ngForm)]="selectedDepartment.departmentLocation" ngControl="departmentLocation" placeholder="location">
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="putDep(selectedDepartment)" title="Add">
      Save
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)=showHide($event) >
      Cancel
    </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You mean [(ngModel)], not [(ngForm)], sth like this:  [(ngModel)]="selected.departmentNo ? :) I tried it too, but the problem is that when I click my edit button, in form input fields there are no  values from my table row. In Angular 1 it easy, don't know what is the problem.

Comment: The error I got: TypeError: Cannot read property 'departmentNo' of undefined in [selected.departmentNo in AppComponent@76:32]